# proguard warning: the configuration keeps the entry point....but not the descriptor class

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I've configured:

```
-keep ,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking public class     org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.** {
    *;
}
```

but still getting the warning:

```
 Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.trusteer.trf.dex_parser { int get_strings_count(org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedDexFile); }', but not the descriptor class 'org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedDexFile'
```

I am using proguard version 4.7 (in Android SDK)

What should I do?

Comment: `-keep, includedescriptorclasses`

Comment: Muhammad's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 33):

You have told Proguard to keep a certain method `void foo(Bar bar);` but to obfuscate the descriptor class `Bar`.

This is only a problem if you are going to invoke the method from an external source as the signature will be changed by the obfuscation (if you use Proguard to obfuscate a library and then use that library in another app).

So have the following choices:

- Configure Proguard to also keep `Bar`.
- Use the `-dontnote` directive to tell Proguard not to print notes like this.

Comment: what does it really mean "invoke the method from an external source"

Comment: From a source outside the app/library that you are obfuscating with Proguard. Eg if you use Proguard to obfuscate a library and then use that library in another app

Comment: It does not help.

Comment: what is a descriptor class? many times, im gonna read a proguard docs and just get thrown into a deeper rabbithole of abstractions ive never heard of. it's no wonder i see most people going the "incorrect" route of throwing `-dontwarn` and `-dontnote` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Note: the configuration keeps the entry point '...', but not the descriptor class '...'
Your configuration contains a -keep option to preserve the given method (or field), but no -keep option for the given class that is an argument type or return type in the method's descriptor. You may then want to keep the class too. Otherwise, ProGuard will obfuscate its name, thus changing the method's signature. The method might then become unfindable as an entry point, e.g. if it is part of a public API. You can automatically keep such descriptor classes with the -keep option modifier includedescriptorclasses (-keep,includedescriptorclasses ...). You can switch off these notes by specifying the -dontnote option.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in your 'proguard-rules.pro' file to fix this problem .

```
-ignorewarnings
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docuemnts](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#allowshrinking):

> allowshrinking Specifies that the entry points specified in the -keep
>   option may be shrunk, even if they have to be preserved otherwise.
>   That is, the entry points may be removed in the shrinking step, but if
>   they are necessary after all, they may not be optimized or obfuscated

So it appears that you need to remove the `allowshrinking` modifier.

Comment: Do you get a new error message? Did you try a different version of ProGuard?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem appears when I add to build.gradle

```
minifyEnable true
```

Official instructions: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Bug https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19250

Sample proguard-rules.pro file:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-ignorewarnings
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I did some digging in the [docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass). You have not supplied your whole configuration file, but I'm guessing that that `com.trusteer.trf.dex_parser` is set to both keep and not to obfuscate.

This means that there is a refrence from `com.trusteer.trf.dex_parser` to a class called `org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedDexFile` that was either shrunk or obfuscated. This means that the link is now broken - `dex_parser` can't import `DexBackedDexFile`.

So either disable shrinking and obfuscation for `DexBackedDexFile`, or allow optimization and obfuscation on `dex_parser`.