# Several new Proguard issues Google Play services v10.2.6 to v11.0.0 in a Multidex project

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-proguard, okhttp

I updated our app to use the most recent Android Firebase SDK v11.0.0 (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20170607) and out of the suddenly we bunch of new proguard errors appear, FYI everything was working well before with proguard.

**Before:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.6'
```

**After:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.0'
```

The issue is that it doesn't seem to be a simple new missing proguard entry, but it seems that it broke the whole thing, suddenly several other libraries appeared to be affected by this change.

**These are the Proguard issues related to the GMS:**

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient { com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfd zza(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.common.zza); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.zza'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { AppMeasurement(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchx); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchx'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void setEventInterceptor(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void registerOnMeasurementEventListener(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void unregisterOnMeasurementEventListener(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void registerOnScreenChangeCallback(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zza); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zza'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { void unregisterOnScreenChangeCallback(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zza); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zza'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics { FirebaseAnalytics(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchx); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchx'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'
```

**additionally, also OkHttp3 was affected, see the errors below:**

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.Cache$Entry { Cache$Entry(okio.Source); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.Cache$Entry { java.util.List readCertificateList(okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.Cache$Entry { void writeCertList(okio.BufferedSink,java.util.List); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.FormBody { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.FormBody { long writeOrCountBytes(okio.BufferedSink,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.HttpUrl { void percentDecode(okio.Buffer,java.lang.String,int,int,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.HttpUrl { void canonicalize(okio.Buffer,java.lang.String,int,int,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.MultipartBody { MultipartBody(okio.ByteString,okhttp3.MediaType,java.util.List); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.MultipartBody { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.MultipartBody { long writeOrCountBytes(okio.BufferedSink,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody { okhttp3.RequestBody create(okhttp3.MediaType,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody$1 { RequestBody$1(okhttp3.MediaType,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody$1 { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody$2 { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.RequestBody$3 { void writeTo(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.ResponseBody { okhttp3.ResponseBody create(okhttp3.MediaType,long,okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.ResponseBody$1 { ResponseBody$1(okhttp3.MediaType,long,okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader { ResponseBody$BomAwareReader(okio.BufferedSource,java.nio.charset.Charset); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.WebSocket { boolean send(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.WebSocketListener { void onMessage(okhttp3.WebSocket,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.Util { boolean discard(okio.Source,int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.Util { boolean skipAll(okio.Source,int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.Util { java.nio.charset.Charset bomAwareCharset(okio.BufferedSource,java.nio.charset.Charset); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1 { CacheInterceptor$1(okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor,okio.BufferedSource,okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheRequest,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1 { CacheInterceptor$1(okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor,okio.BufferedSource,okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheRequest,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1 { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$2 { DiskLruCache$2(okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache,okio.Sink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Sink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$Editor$1 { DiskLruCache$Editor$1(okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$Editor,okio.Sink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Sink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$Entry { void writeLengths(okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot { DiskLruCache$Snapshot(okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache,java.lang.String,long,okio.Source[],long[]); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.FaultHidingSink { FaultHidingSink(okio.Sink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Sink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache.FaultHidingSink { void write(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.FileOperator { void write(long,okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.FileOperator { void read(long,okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay { Relay(java.io.RandomAccessFile,okio.Source,long,okio.ByteString,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay { Relay(java.io.RandomAccessFile,okio.Source,long,okio.ByteString,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay { okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay edit(java.io.File,okio.Source,okio.ByteString,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay { okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay edit(java.io.File,okio.Source,okio.ByteString,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay { void writeHeader(okio.ByteString,long,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.cache2.Relay$RelaySource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection$1 { RealConnection$1(okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection,boolean,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink,okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection$1 { RealConnection$1(okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection,boolean,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink,okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody { RealResponseBody(okhttp3.Headers,okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec { Http1Codec(okhttp3.OkHttpClient,okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec { Http1Codec(okhttp3.OkHttpClient,okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec { void detachTimeout(okio.ForwardingTimeout); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ForwardingTimeout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSink { void write(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSink { void write(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$UnknownLengthSource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Header { Header(okio.ByteString,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Header { Header(okio.ByteString,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Header { Header(okio.ByteString,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack { okio.ByteString checkLowercase(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack$Reader { Hpack$Reader(int,okio.Source); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack$Reader { Hpack$Reader(int,int,okio.Source); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack$Writer { Hpack$Writer(okio.Buffer); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack$Writer { Hpack$Writer(int,boolean,okio.Buffer); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Hpack$Writer { void writeByteString(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec$StreamFinishingSource { Http2Codec$StreamFinishingSource(okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec,okio.Source); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection { void writeData(int,boolean,okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection { void pushDataLater(int,okio.BufferedSource,int,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$6 { Http2Connection$6(okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[],int,okio.Buffer,int,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$Builder { okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$Builder socket(java.net.Socket,java.lang.String,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$Builder { okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$Builder socket(java.net.Socket,java.lang.String,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable { void data(boolean,int,okio.BufferedSource,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable { void goAway(int,okhttp3.internal.http2.ErrorCode,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable { void alternateService(int,java.lang.String,okio.ByteString,java.lang.String,int,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader { Http2Reader(okio.BufferedSource,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader { int readMedium(okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader$ContinuationSource { Http2Reader$ContinuationSource(okio.BufferedSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader$ContinuationSource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader$Handler { void data(boolean,int,okio.BufferedSource,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader$Handler { void goAway(int,okhttp3.internal.http2.ErrorCode,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader$Handler { void alternateService(int,java.lang.String,okio.ByteString,java.lang.String,int,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream { void receiveData(okio.BufferedSource,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink { void write(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource { long read(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource { void receive(okio.BufferedSource,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer { Http2Writer(okio.BufferedSink,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer { void data(boolean,int,okio.Buffer,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer { void dataFrame(int,byte,okio.Buffer,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer { void writeMedium(okio.BufferedSink,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Huffman { void encode(okio.ByteString,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Huffman { void encode(okio.ByteString,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.Huffman { int encodedLength(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.PushObserver { boolean onData(int,okio.BufferedSource,int,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.http2.PushObserver$1 { boolean onData(int,okio.BufferedSource,int,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { void onReadMessage(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { void onReadPing(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { void onReadPong(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { boolean send(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { boolean send(okio.ByteString,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket { boolean pong(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$Close { RealWebSocket$Close(int,okio.ByteString,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$Message { RealWebSocket$Message(int,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$Streams { RealWebSocket$Streams(boolean,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$Streams { RealWebSocket$Streams(boolean,okio.BufferedSource,okio.BufferedSink); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader { WebSocketReader(boolean,okio.BufferedSource,okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader { void readMessage(okio.Buffer); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback { void onReadMessage(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback { void onReadPing(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback { void onReadPong(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter { WebSocketWriter(boolean,okio.BufferedSink,java.util.Random); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSink'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter { void writePing(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter { void writePong(okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter { void writeClose(int,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter { void writeControlFrameSynchronized(int,okio.ByteString); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.ByteString'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter$FrameSink { void write(okio.Buffer,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Buffer'
```

more info:

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.4'
    }`

`ext.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 25
ext.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "26.0.0"`

Comment: First of all, the proguard works before dexing so multidex information is redundant

Comment: Did you update only play services? So no upgrade for build tools chain or android gradle plugin?

Comment: Does it fail in AS or from command line as well?

Comment: Have you looked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690994/proguard-warning-the-configuration-keeps-the-entry-point-but-not-the-descrip?

Comment: @EugenMartynov with proguard enabled, it always fails via command line...AS (deploying on the device works normally)

Comment: the only change was the firebase version..the rest remains the same.

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: I have suspicions that proguard configuration is changed in one of these dependencies

Comment: @JakeWarthon mentioned a bug that happens if you use OkHttp and Play Services v11. A fix can be found on his Twitter account https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/872632310142832642

Comment: thanks @JakeWarthon switching to Google Play services 11.0.1 just works without any extra change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the *Android Firebase SDK v11.0.0* is doomed, the ***Android Firebase SDK v11.0.1*** fixed it without any extra change.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this [Proguard Troubleshooting manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#descriptorclass) wherein it was noted that for the encountered warnings, `the configuration keeps the entry point`...`but not the descriptor class`:

> Your configuration contains a `-keep` option to preserve the given method (or field), but no `-keep` option for the given class that is an argument type or return type in the method's descriptor. You may then want to keep the class too. Otherwise, ProGuard will obfuscate its name, thus changing the method's signature. The method might then become unfindable as an entry point. You can automatically keep such descriptor classes with the `-keep` option modifier [`includedescriptorclasses`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#includedescriptorclasses) (-keep,includedescriptorclasses ...). You can switch off these notes by specifying the [`-dontnote`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#dontnote) option.

For additional insights, these SO posts might also help:

- [Proguard: can't find referenced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583148/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class)
- [Proguard unresolved references to classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050424/proguard-unresolved-references-to-classes)

Summing it all, you may want to try adding these two lines to your Proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: I thought we use proguard so we don't have to keep everything in the package. If anything proguard should be used as a precision tool.