# Can I ignore Proguard note "but not the descriptor class 'com.google.gson.Gson'"?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, gson

Even though I know I can suppress these notes using

```
-dontnote okhttp3.**, okio.**, retrofit2.**
```

I want to know from my fellow developers here whether it is really safe to ignore notes coming from my proguard logs

> Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'okhttp3.ResponseBody {
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody
>   create(okhttp3.MediaType,long,okio.BufferedSource); }', **but not the
>   descriptor class 'okio.BufferedSource'**

Similarly, I am getting the following from `retrofit2`

> Note: the configuration keeps the entry point
>   'retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter {
>   GsonRequestBodyConverter(com.google.gson.Gson,com.google.gson.TypeAdapter);
>   }', **but not the descriptor class 'com.google.gson.Gson'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proguard warning: the configuration keeps the entry point....but not the descriptor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690994/proguard-warning-the-configuration-keeps-the-entry-point-but-not-the-descrip)